# need help to send int array from C# to arduino

Tags: c#, arrays, arduino

I have the following integer array  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

I need to send it to Arduino UNO.

I've tried to send it as array of byte but it doesn't work.

**C# code:**

```
using System.IO.Ports;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{serialPort1.Open();}

byte[] OUT = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 }; 

serialPort1.Write(OUT, 0, 12);
```

**arduino code**

```
void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);

  for (byte aPin = start; aPin <= 13 ; aPin++) {
    pinMode(aPin, OUTPUT);}

  for (byte apin = start; apin <= 13 ; apin++) {
    digitalWrite(apin,HIGH);}


}


void loop(){

//Serial communication step
//Serial.write("6564456464646");

if(Serial.available()){

  for(char j=0;j<Serial.available();j++)
  {input[j]=Serial.read();}
```

Comment: Can you post your code samples.

Comment: How does the Arduino know when the end of data is reached?  A connection which is a steam stays open after the message is sent so the Arduino sits in the for loop waiting for more data.  When sending binary data (bytes) you need to send a byte count at beginning of the message indicating how may bytes are going to be transmitted.  You could alway send the same number of bytes, or put a terminating character at end of data.

Comment: i submit my C# code below. so you can see it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;
namespace AGAING
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
       // int[] OUT = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }; // The array must be send by AUNO the resend to it.
        byte[] OUT = new byte[12];
        byte lamp = 0; // The index of lamp type array, and the indecation of the lamp type in the OUT array ti the AUNO.
        string[] lampType = { "ENERGY SAVER", "TUNGSTEN", "FLUORESCENT", "METAL HALIDE" }; // Array for lamp type identification.

        int sample; // The index of the report matrix, and giving number of test we did.
        int[] endsample = new int [12]; //index array for saving the ended sample date.

        int reportlenth = 3; // lenth of reporting arrays
        string[] smplNo = new string[3]; //Array for sample number reporting.
        string[] smpltype = new string[3]; // Array for sample lamp type reporting.
        string[] startdate = new string[3]; // Array for sample starting date reporting.
        string[] enddate = new string[3]; // Array for sample ending date reporting.

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
         //   getportnames();   
            //serialPort1.Open();

        }

      //  void getportnames()
        //{
          // string[] port = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
           //PortcomboBox1.Items.AddRange(port);

       // }

        void warning(string warning) // Worning message properties.
        {
            MessageBox.Show(warning, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            serialPort1.Open();
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(Object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            serialPort1.Close();
        }

        private void lamptype_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) // Projection the combo box of lamp type to the OUT Array
        {
            if (lamptype.SelectedIndex == 0)
            { lamp = 1; }
            else if (lamptype.SelectedIndex == 1)
            { lamp = 2; }
            else if (lamptype.SelectedIndex == 2)
            { lamp = 3; }
            else if (lamptype.SelectedIndex == 3)
            { lamp = 4; }
            else if (lamptype.SelectedIndex == -1)
            { lamp = 0; }
        }

        private void out1_CheckedChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (out1.Checked)
            {// If check box selected change its properties
                out1.Font = new Font(out1.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
                //Change text box properties.
                sampleno1.Clear();
                sampleno1.Enabled = true;
                //Change text box properties.
                enddate1.Clear();
                datetime1.Clear();
                lamptype1.Clear();
            }
            else {// unless reset the check box
                out1.Font = new Font(out1.Font, FontStyle.Regular);
                //Change text box properties.
                sampleno1.Enabled = false;
                // Reset the lamp type selection.
                lamptype.SelectedIndex = -1;
                lamptype.Text = "__Select lamp type__";
            }
            //
            serialPort1.Write(OUT, 0, 12);
        }

        private void run1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {//Check if any data are not marked give wornings.
            if (out1.Checked == false) { warning("Select output"); }
            else if (lamptype.SelectedIndex < 0) { warning("Select Lamp Type"); }
            else if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(sampleno1.Text)) { warning("Enter sample number"); }
            else if (sampleno1.TextLength != 10) { warning("Enter sample number correctly"); }
            else
            {// If yes change check box properties  
                out1.Enabled = false;
                // Change run button properties  
                run1.Text = "In Use";
                run1.Enabled = false;
                run1.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
                run1.Font = new Font(run1.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
                // Change text box properties  
                sampleno1.Enabled = false;
                // Change stop button properties  
                stop1.Enabled = true;
                stop1.BackColor = Color.OrangeRed;
                stop1.Font = new Font(stop1.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
                // Marking lamp type na d aoth data in text bos and reset lamp type combo box 
                lamptype1.Text = lampType[lamp - 1];
                lamptype.Text = "__Select lamp type__";
                // Show the starting date. 
                datetime1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy, hh:mm:ss");
                // Save the sample data.
                smplNo[sample] = sampleno1.Text;    // Save the sample number.
                smpltype[sample] = lamptype1.Text;  // Save the lamp type date.
                startdate[sample] = datetime1.Text; // Save the starting date.
                // Save the reporting index for the ending date.
                endsample[0] = sample;
                // Increase the reporting index to give the sample counter and show it.
                sample++;
                MessageBox.Show("This is test no. " + sample);
                // Worning to reset the saving data arraies. the reset it.
                if (sample == reportlenth - 1)
                { warning("Only 1 more sample and the reporting system will reset, please inform the responsible"); }
                else if (sample == reportlenth)
                { warning("The reporting system will reset, please inform the responsible");
                    sample = 0; }
                //******************************************************************************//
                // Set the output lamp type in the OUT array for AUNO.
                OUT[0] = lamp;
            }
            //
            //serialPort1.WriteLine("$");
            serialPort1.Write(OUT, 0, 12);
        }
```

Comment: this is part of my C# code that ended with sending the array OUT which is 12 index where i'll repeat this run1_Click for 12 times and that will complete all array data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this part for c# part:

```
         Connect();
        if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
        {
            int MyInt = ToInt32(lblFirstNumber.Text);
            byte[] b = GetBytes(MyInt);
            serialPort1.Write(b, 0, 1);

            int MyInt2 = ToInt32(txtFirstNumber.Text);
            byte[] z = GetBytes(MyInt2);
            serialPort1.Write(z, 0, 1);

            int MyInt3 = ToInt32(txtSecondNumber.Text);
            byte[] p = GetBytes(MyInt3);
            serialPort1.Write(p, 0, 1);

            serialPort1.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please control your connection");
        }
```